# What would it take to create Markdown support for Notes App?

Tags: applescript, notes.app

I'm a heavy Notes user and I was wondering if it's at all possible to create limited markdown support for Notes app. For example, to create syntax highlighting for snippets like this.

```
const(a, b) => a + b;
```

Is it at all customazible?

Comment: SnippetsLab is a good Apple-Notes style app for storing code snippets (I have no affiliation with them, but since I discovered it it's become part of my regular workflows).

Answer (score 3):

No, the notes web app and iOS app and the other versions has no "code formatting skins" or extensibility for adding syntax coloring and formatting from markdown.

There is support for [coloration and text formatting](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/icloud-ipad/mmc0cd6edf/icloud) and copy/paste preserves that, so your best bet would be to process the markdown externally to the app and then paste in the results.

Or to work in an app with syntax coloring. That might make an excellent follow on [software-recommendation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) question.

Comment: That seems a shame... after Markdown has been around for as many years as it has, and still not being adopted.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NotesCmdr](https://smallest.app/notescmdr/) which adds Markdown style syntax to Notes. Although I do not see anything for syntax highlighting.